# How to specify ClassParser constructor parameter?

Tags: java, bcel

I'm trying to use ClassParser to get method parameter names, ClassParser constructor takes class name as parameter for example:

```
ClassParser parser = new ClassParser("Main.class");
```

I 'm trying to set the parameter to String class I 've tried to use "String.class" but it doesn't work. I've also used "java.lang.String.class" but it doesn't work. Finally, I've tried this.getClass().getResource("java/lang/String").toString() but also this doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Where is this ClassParser class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is BCEL? Then ClassParser does not really take a a class name parameter, but rather an input stream, a file name or a zip file and entry (a.k.a jar file entry).  I would expect that

```
ClassParser parser = new ClassParser("your/package/name/Main.class");
```

would work, given that your class is not part of a jar file.

Comment: Yes, javadoc (http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassParser.html#constructor_summary) explains all clearly: the constructor accepts a filename and/or InputSteram.

Comment: the problem is that some of my class are part of a jar